# too many 'where' clauses in rails(using MySQL) for one-to-one connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a kind of restaurant description database and users can search which restaurant is what they are looking for. But there are too many columns that describes different attributes and my search form doesn't get much queries(? I don't know it is the right expression in this context, I'm so newbie in programming...) just for category, locations and names.

So I made one distinct database(rest_key) which looks like this

```
class CreateRestKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rest_keys do |t|
      t.integer :category
      t.string :name
      t.string :addr
      t.integer :restaurant_id  # reference for real Restaurant model
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and my Restaurant model & RestKey model looks like below (one-to-one association)

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :rest_key
end

class RestKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

and I wanted at first, get queries from users and find RestKey, then retrieve restaurants related with that RestKey. This kind of logic

```
Restaurant.joins(:rest_key).where("rest_keys.category = ? AND 
                                   rest_keys.name LIKE ? AND 
                                   rest_keys.addr LIKE ?", 
                                   search_category, "%#{search_name}%", "%#{search_addr}%")
```

But the problem is that users can put many words in search_addr input box for accuracy. So I thought first I can make array for address like `arr = params[:search_addr].split` and do the previous process with many many where clauses.

```
Restaurant.joins(:rest_key).where("rest_keys.category = ? AND 
                                   rest_keys.name LIKE ? AND 
                                   rest_keys.addr LIKE ? AND   # addr search starts
                                   rest_keys.addr LIKE ? AND 
                                   rest_keys.addr LIKE ? AND 
                                   rest_keys.addr LIKE ? AND 
                                   rest_keys.addr LIKE ?", 
                                   search_category, "%#{search_name}%", "%#{arr[0]}%", "%#{arr[1]}%", "%#{arr[2]}%", "%#{arr[3]}%", "%#{arr[4]}%")
```

Even though I have so poor knowledge, I could feel this code can't be called code. Can I loop the where clauses or is there any idea that can filter with address input? Any comments will be a huge help for me!(I think users can type address words in odd order, so I have to split them and filter with every words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that SQL can have string as the query in rails. So I changed the above codes like

```
sql = ""
array = []
params[:search_addr].split.each do |addr|
  addr = "'%" + addr + "%'"
  array << "rest_keys.addr LIKE " + addr
end
sql = array.join(' AND ')

Restaurant.joins(:rest_key).where(sql)
```

I hope this answer can help anyone newbie like me. If there is a better way, please let me know, it will be a good lesson to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Instead of doing `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` you can simple use `matches_any` with `array`

```
rest_key_table = RestKey.arel_table
rest_key_table[:addr].matches_any(arr)
```

You can use below  way

You can try it by part by part

```
rest_key_table = RestKey.arel_table
@rest_categories = Restaurant.where(:rest_keys => {:category => search_category}, :joins => :rest_keys)
@rest_categories.where(rest_key_table[:addr].matches_any(arr))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! but that way is just making syntax error for me.(now I can't fully understand your solutions so I could not figure out what part is the problem)

Comment: SyntaxError: (irb):8: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...name].matches_any(search_name), rest_key_table[:addr].matche...
...                               ^
(irb):8: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
...table[:addr].matches_any(arr) }, :joins => :rest_keys)
sorry.... I couldn't understand this.

Comment: Thank you @Rajarshi Das! I could learn new thing "arel_table and matches_any". But I think this method is retrieving data with operator OR(not AND because I wanted to filter address with all arr values)